# Dividing a long code into parts

Tags: manipulate, code-organization

I have long code that I would like to divide in several parts (for readability) to be saved in different files. Then, later, I could use those parts into a different notebook. The parts I am thinking of are not functions per se but only part of the code. I have tried something like this:

```
Manipulate[
 Get["Manipulate\\Main.txt"];
 Plot[b[f],{f,fmin,fmax}],
 Get["Manipulate\\Controls.txt"]
 ]
```

Is this possible at all?

Comment: Certainly. Turn your code into functions, save them in packages, and delineate which parts are private implementation details vs. public functions you want to expose. Importing fragments of code that are not functions or nicely contained units you can reason about will likely to lead to things leaking everywhere and make debugging harder.

Comment: I think it might be a little trickier because `Manipulate` moves in mysterious ways.

Answer (score 3):

One way is as follows. It is important that the code is inserted into `Manipulate[]` without being evaluated.  Note the use of `Hold` and `OwnValues`.

In a file, say `"/tmp/body.wl"` or better yet, https://pastebin.com/raw/TbzQYHqz:

```
body = Hold[
   b = Sin[aa*n #] &;
   Plot[b[f], {f, fmin, fmax}]
   ];
```

In another file, say `"/tmp/controls.wl"` or better yet, https://pastebin.com/raw/0bt8a6x7:

```
controls = Hold[
   {fmin, 0, 1},
   {fmax, 2, 3},
   {n, 1, 5, 1}
   ];
```

Then

```
Clear[body, controls];
fmin = -1;  (* to show global definitions do not affect the result *)
b = 0;      (* ditto, but this is overwritten when /tmp/body.wl is read in *)
aa = 2;     (* a global variable used in  body  *)
<< "https://pastebin.com/raw/TbzQYHqz"; (* read in body *)
<< "https://pastebin.com/raw/0bt8a6x7"; (* read in controls *)


Hold[
     body,
     controls] /.
    OwnValues@body /.
   OwnValues@controls //
  Flatten //
 Apply[Manipulate]
```

[image]

If you want something more complicated as shown in your example, then things get more intricate, depending on how much variation you want to be able to handle.  For instance, moving `Plot[..]` out of the definition of `body`:

```
body = Hold[
   b = Sin[aa*n #] &
   ];

Hold[
    body,
    Plot[b[f], {f, fmin, fmax}],
    controls] /. OwnValues@body /. OwnValues@controls /. 
 Hold[Hold[b1_], b2_, Hold[c___]] :> Manipulate[b1; b2, c]
```